# Starting sql server despite database files no longer existing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have the following situation:

- A sql server 2014 is installed
- While the server was shutdown the hard drive the databases were on had troubles which resulted in the loss of these files

So now I have the situation that the server has databases configured to be existing where the files don't exist any longer.

When I now try to start the sql server via the configuration tools it does not start and in the log files I see that he throws an error that he doesn't find the database files. When I tried to copy the same files there from another server I still had the same problem but the error message was now "access denied" (as naturally they had different users).

So my question is: What (aside from a reinstall) can I do to get the sql server up and running again?

Comment: Why the closing vote? (would be good to know as I doublechecked before posting if also server related problems are in the stackoverflow part of the stackexchange, if it is still the wrong subeset would be good to know)

Comment: The close votes are for moving this to DBA.

Comment: Ah tnx for the answer there. I overlooked the DBA when skimming through the stackexchange parts and only saw the superusers. Makes sense both ways. As an answer is given I can't delete anyway.

Comment: That's why you *must* backup your databases. Copying some files from another server won't work for the system database because a lot of that data is machine-specific. As for the other databases you can detach them from the other server (eg using the context menu), copy them and then attach them to the target server

Comment: your options depend on what databases you've lost. This article (if you lost system databases) may be of use: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207003.aspx

Comment: From what I just heard the system databases are still existing only the user databases went datawrecked

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that doesnt work as for attaching them again the server needs to be running which is the main problem atm as he just doesn't start up

Comment: If the system databases are OK the server should start up. Unless you specified a *different* drive for system and data databases though, they no longer exist. You should provide all relevant info (with the exact error messages) both here *and* at the DBA site for people to help you.

Comment: Ah didn't know that it was relevant but yeah you are correct it is a different drive for system (C) and for data databases (D))

Answer (score 0):

Change the database file permissions to allow access for SQL Server. Look at an existing file to see what permissions must be configured.

Comment: To make sure: You mean the windows file permissions of the copied files?

Comment: Yes. You said that you got a access denied error. Seems like a logical choice to solve that error.